# Сворачивание приложения

Tags: android

В моем приложении присутствует SplashActivity, которое при старте автоматически перенаправляет пользователя на MainActivity или на вторую активность в зависимости от сценария. В MainActivity присутствует код для выхода (сворачивания) приложения по кнопке Back. После срабатывания этого кода появляется черный экран. Вопрос - какой код добавить в SplashActivity, чтобы этого черного экрана не было? И еще есть проблема - запрос на выход теперь есть в каждой активности (видимо, наследуется от MainActivity), как этого избежать?
SplashActivity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        System.currentTimeMillis();


        int x = 1543845463; // задано конкретное время в UNIX
        if (x > System.currentTimeMillis()/1000) { // вызываем системное время, делим его на 1000 для получения UNIX
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent); // реализуем первый сценарий
        }
        else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Warning.class);
            startActivity(intent); // реализуем второй сценарий
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Внимание!")
                .setMessage("Вы действительно хотите выйти?")
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                    }
                }).create().show();
    }
```

Comment: Почему бы не сделать в MainActivity обработку вашего сценария? Это исправит вашу проблему

Comment: Пытался отрабатывать нажатие на Back переход на SplashActivity с определенным флагом, а там организовывать выход по этому флагу. Но в SplashActivity почему то сценарий выхода не отрабатывается...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

надо добавить `android:noHistory="true"` в AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:noHistory="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

С `MainActivity` на `back` вы возвращаетесь в `SplashActivity`.

Как минимум, задайте в `SplashActivity` разметку:

```
setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
```

Либо добавьте тот же `finish();` (как в `else`)

Не знаю, какого поведения вы хотите добиться, но черный экран именно из-за отсутствия разметки.

**upd**: для того, чтобы ваша `MainActivity` была единственной (чтобы выход из нее выходил из приложения), можете использовать флаг:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
```

перед `startActivity(intent);`

Comment: Хотелось бы, чтобы этого экрана вообще не было. Чтобы из MainActivity можно было бы полностью "выйди" из приложения, минуя этот черный экран

Comment: `finish()` после  `startActivity(intent); // реализуем первый сценарий` добавили?

Comment: @ru38irk, немного обновил ответ